# How to use the use single variable from Get-content command

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I have a tfvar file in which I have mutiple variables. I have get the content of it by using this command in powershell.

```
    $product_list = (Get-Content "../templates/variables/dev.terraform.tfvars" -Raw)
    Write-Host $product_list.virtual_network_address_space
```

And I got this output:

```
    client_name_prefix = "f"
    resource_group_postfix = "rg"
    environment_name = "dev"
    instance = "04"

    # Storage Account
    storage_account_tier = "Standard"
    account_replication_type = "GRS"
    container_access_type = "private"
    storage_account_container_name1= "drivemate"
    storage_account_container_name2= "fair-private"
    storage_account_container_name3= "fair-public"
```

What I want now is to get the value of "**resource_group_postfix**"

Comment: `$product_list.virtual_network_address_space.resource_group_postfix`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata):

```
$Product_list |ConvertFrom-StringData

Name                           Value
----                           -----
instance                       "04"
storage_account_container_nam… "fair-public"
storage_account_tier           "Standard"
resource_group_postfix         "rg"
environment_name               "dev"
storage_account_container_nam… "drivemate"
storage_account_container_nam… "fair-private"
client_name_prefix             "f"
account_replication_type       "GRS"
container_access_type          "private"
```

```
($Product_list |ConvertFrom-StringData).resource_group_postfix
"rg"
```

And in case you want to lose the double quotes:

```
($Product_list |ConvertFrom-StringData).resource_group_postfix.trim('"')
rg
```

Comment: what if I have some ARRAY in the file, It return System.Collections.Hashtable

Comment: How to skip the Arrays?

Comment: "*ARRAY in the file*" ? There is nothing in your question about that. Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73372804/edit) your question (or open a new one) and add a correct [mcve] information.